# TV disappears as audio device on single display

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, windows-10-v2004

I have two monitors and a TV connected to my Windows 10 PC. Whenever I set the TV (connected through HDMI) as the only active display, its audio device disappears from the playback devices list in sound controls, and Windows defaults back to my regular audio output (speakers).

If I use the TV *in addition to* the other displays (i.e. I extend the display to it), the audio device *does* appear and Windows automatically switches to it as intended.

#### Why does the TV disappear from the audio devices list, and how can I force Windows to detect it again?

I’ve tested with a laptop, and it is able to use the TV as a single display without losing the audio device, so I suspect it’s a software problem on the PC.

Specifically, I noticed this change in behavior around the time I installed the May 2020 update.

I’ve tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Nvidia drivers (thereby also reinstalling the HDMI audio drivers), but that has no effect on the problem.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. I used to have my external monitor as LG TV (on playback devices list) and audio worked great before May 2020 update. After that, it usually plays some seconds after Windows startup, but then it stops producing any audio at all (even if I have signal on audio indicators). 
Now on playback device I have Intel Audio(R) Display Drivers - HDMI 1 (Intel Audio(R) Display Drivers)

Comment: Have you tried checking for optional driver updates in Windows update?

Comment: you mean 'update drivers' on device manager > "Search automatically for updated driver software" ? Yes I tried but WindowsUpdate doesn't find anything newer

Comment: I meant in Windows Update > View Optional Updates (if it exists) > Driver Updates. That's new since version 2004, and I believe the method you describe no longer searches online that way.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have any 'optional updates'

Comment: I'm also having similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think I just found a possible fix to this issue: Open Device Manager, and right click on “Audio inputs and outputs” and select “Scan for hardware changes.”

May have to do it if it keeps disappearing, but works for me when my TV disappears from the list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem! (windows 11 + lg 4k monitor), Just select "fix audio problems" over the speaker icon at task bar > right click everytime.  its annoying to do this everytime after the monitor or the pc sleeps but seems no other way to solve.